# Lookback Verify Second Email Address

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, token, loopbackjs

I am currently attempting to change a users email address in loopback after a user has registered with a different email address.

Once the user changes their email address the new email address needs to be stored as newEmail until the user has verified the new email, which at that point it will overwrite the members primary email in the User endpoint.

My question is, how am I able to verify this email address as loopbacks Member.verify only takes an id as an argument and checks against the primary email address stored, I need to be able to check against the 'newEmail' property?

My current 'member.json' file looks like:-

```
{
  "name": "Member",
  "plural": "Members",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "newEmail": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Member.verify only takes an id as an argument

Do you mean the [confirm](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/6ddf268cb626521971f5e5b63382bf08af78285a/common/models/user.js#L870) method takes the userId?  If you did, the email is irrelevant at this point, it only compares the a token to that user's email verification token.

Storing another set of emails would mean duplicating the [verify](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/6ddf268cb626521971f5e5b63382bf08af78285a/common/models/user.js#L692) and confirm methods and creating another set of endpoints and model properties to hold the new email information.  It would seem simpler to set `user.emailValidated` to `false` and put the `newEmail` into `user.email`. This would force re-validation with the new email, though it would forget the old information.

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Registering-users.html

Comment: The issue is it would forget the old information, so the user would not be able to login with their old email. I did think about this route, but what if the user puts accidentally types the wrong email address.

Comment: You could require a username for every account, which would never change and could be used to authenticate with the password and reset the email again in the case of a typo.

Comment: Unfortunately using a username is not an option.

Comment: I linked the two methods which are used to verify emails, creating a set of duplicate methods for your extended model and changing the name and property accessors to your extended model's `newVerificationToken` and `newEmail` methods seems like your best bet, albeit not a very DRY one.